# passing Google Places data to UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, casting, gmsplace

I am trying to pass data collected after selecting a place from GMSAutocompleteViewController, and having some issues. I am getting this error: Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x1afeb5c50) to 'UILabel' (0x1afedd508). Not sure what I am doing wrong...thanks for any and all help!

```
    // MARK: GOOGLE AUTO COMPLETE DELEGATE

    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

        // Do something with the selected place.
        // A hotel in Saigon with an attribution.
        // let placeID = "ChIJV4k8_9UodTERU5KXbkYpSYs"
        let placeID = place.placeID 

        placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let place = place else {
                print("No place details for \(placeID)")
                return
            }

            print("Place name \(place.name)")
            print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
            print("Place placeID \(place.placeID)")
            print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
        })

        //
        let selectedPlace = place.name
        self.placeNameLabel = (selectedPlace as AnyObject) as! UILabel

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        setupConfirmationPopUp()

    }


// label I am trying to pass the place.name to
    lazy var placeNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let placeNameLabel = UILabel()
        placeNameLabel.textColor = .black
        placeNameLabel.text = "Are you sure you want to add < Placename Placename > to places you have visited?"
        placeNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 120, width: 200, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude) // use constraints later
        placeNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        placeNameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        placeNameLabel.sizeToFit()
        placeNameLabel.layer.zPosition = 1
        placeNameLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return placeNameLabel
    }()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.placeNameLabel=UILabel()
if let name = selectedPlace as? String
{
   self.placeNameLabel.text = name
}
```

You have to assign the text to the `UILabel`'s `text` property. A UILabel does display text but it does much more than that so it has more attributes, like: backgroundColor, size, frame, bounds, etc.
So the text part is just one of many properties that a UILabel has and you have to explicitly specify that.

Btw you can remove the first line if you created the label in a Storyboard and connected it with an outlet.

By the way:

This:

```
guard let place = place else {
    print("No place details for \(placeID)")
    return
}
```

always returns true, so you can completely forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for any cast (and certainly not two). Simply do:

```
self.placeNameLabel.text = place.name
```

You were trying to assign the string to a label. You need to assign the string to the label's text.

One other serious issue. You need to update the label inside the completion handler of `lookUpPlaceID`. As you have it now, you set the label to the `place` parameter passed to the view controller method but you need to use the `place` parameter passed to the completion handler of the `lookupPlaceID` method. And since updating the label is a UI action, you must set the label on the main queue using `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    let placeID = place.placeID 

    placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let place = place else {
            print("No place details for \(placeID)")
            return
        }

        print("Place name \(place.name)")
        print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
        print("Place placeID \(place.placeID)")
        print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.placeNameLabel = place.name
        }
    })

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    setupConfirmationPopUp()

}
```